# how do I add a ga event to my php redirect code?

Tags: php, events, google-analytics

I have multiple affiliate links which have there own PHP redirect file on my hosting server. The redirect page www.myredirectpageonserver.com is clicked

I have a simple php code on my redirect page:

```
< ?php
header("Location: myaffiliatesite.com");
? >
```

how do I add GA event tracking to this without losing the redirect. Please help, I keep getiing near the answer but the code never works?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add good analytics to file which contain redirection. It is because there can't be any content sent when you want to use `header("location:").`

You can add google analytics code to redirected page.

There may be also trick with opening another page with **curl** or **file_get_contents()**. You can do it and put the GA code inside this page. In this case when cookies are allowed(curl) you should be able to obtain statistics for this page.